# Returned non zero exit status 101 giving an error when I tried create a Virtual environment

Tags: python, virtualenv

When I run `py -3 -m venv venv` on command prompt to create a virtual environment it fails.

```
"Error: Command '['C:\\Users\\Guest\\Desktop\\Python Web 
 App\\venv\\Scripts\\python.exe', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default- 
 pip']' returned non-zero exit status 101.
```

How to fix this? I've installed the latest Python Version. I'm stuck here on my way to set up Flask for web development.

Comment: Did you have pyvenv-win installed at any time?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python3.8 venv returned exit status 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61641280/python3-8-venv-returned-exit-status-101)

Comment: @npengra317 I have. Any tips?

Comment: I believe the issue is caused by a space in the path to your executable. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71039131/windows-python-3-10-2-fails-to-run-python-m-venv-venv) and this [issue](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/90844) on github.

Answer (score 7):

This happened after I upgraded from python3.8 to python3.9.

```
sudo apt install python3.9-venv
```

should solve the issue

Comment: same, I had python 3.6 in my Ubuntu, and I installed 3.9, and then when I tried creating a new environment I ran into this error and your solution worked

Answer (score 6):

I tried reinstalling Python to no avail. This problem seems to occur when copying the python executable doesn't work (fully) for whatever reason (seems to be related to PyCharm). I recreated my venv with the `--clear --symlinks`:

```
python -m venv --clear --symlinks ./venv
```

Answer (score 5):

I had this problem - the workaround was to uninstall Python and reinstall it with the `Install for all users` option. See my longer answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62207756/11308690

Comment: Instead of giving the link to your other answer, please flag the question as duplicate

Comment: I would if I could! I'm not able to do that until the other answer is accepted or upvoted it seems.

Comment: I just flagged as duplicate, let's see it it is accepted

Comment: Installing for all users does not solve the problem. The error persists.

Answer (score -2):

I also faced the same problem after upgrading to python 3.9.2 "***Error: Command '['C:\Users\Chicool Ph G\PycharmProjects\InvenoryTrackingSystem\venv\Scripts\python.exe', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default- pip']' returned non-zero exit status 101***"

It worked;

1. unistall the Python 3.9.2
2. reinstall the Python 3.9.2
3. Select *Custom install*
4. Check(Tick) *install for all users*
5. Click **install**

Comment: Same as first answer to this question.