# Unable to add interpreter in pycharm , getting error exit status 101

Tags: python, windows, pycharm

I am unable to add an interpretor in pycharm . I have searched many forums but unable to solve .

Error:Command

```
'['C:\\Users\\USER NAME \\PycharmProjects\\pythonProject\\venv\\Scripts\\python.exe', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']' returned non-zero exit status 101.
```

I have python Python 3.7.8 in Windows 10 installed.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Possible [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61641280/python3-8-venv-returned-exit-status-101/62207756#62207756)

Comment: Hi, i cannot try this since the option is disabled and i tried to run as admin but it still does not enable

Comment: please refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61371606/returned-non-zero-exit-status-101-giving-an-error-when-i-tried-create-a-virtual) may be  useful

Comment: Is the venv exist and valid? Try running the command in the terminal, does it work? P.S. try to contact PyCharm's support pycharm-support@jetbrains.com and send them `idea.log` from **Help | Show Log in ...**.

Comment: Thanks @gowridev and Neo  it has got resolved .I have used python 3.6.5 and then used the option to install for all users manually and by not clicking the option usually displayed at the home screen of the installer

Answer (score 0):

You can try by going in the Pycharm UI. File-> Settings->Project Interpreter and Click the wheel sign and you can add the interpreter.

Comment: hi  simplecode and  @NeoNØVÅ7 I have tried both things . Installed Python 3.8.0 which gave me the ability  to install for all user options as well as tried clicking on the wheel sign as suggested by this comment  but it does not work and I am stuck at the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a space in the path to your original python.exe? Most likely hidden as "USER NAME"? If so, look in "C:\Users" directory for a text file "USER" (being the first part of your account, without any extension). Delete this file and it'll likely to work again.

The same error happens with `venv` in Windows. See [This Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71039131) for more details.